# Chmod 755 and 751

Tags: linux, unix, chmod

Doing chmod 755 on a directory gives me drwxr-xr-x.  Should it not give me drwxr-xr-xr  since 5 is read,execute?

And Doing chmod 751 on a directory give me drwxr-x--x.  Should that not give me drwxr-xr-x?

Kindly explain.

Answer (score 10):

The bits are groups of three the results are correct, I do not really get the point you misunderstood. 5 is read, execute but the order of rwx does not change. Consider them as switches, they might be on (r/w/x) or off (-). Here again an overview of the values:

```
7(8) = 111(2) => rwx
5(8) = 101(2) => r-x
1(8) = 001(2) => --x
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: It's rwx. Read. Write. Execute.

Not wxr or xrw or rxw. It's only one of the 3! different ways of arranging the letters. This may clear up some of your confusion.

Also, `chmod` works with an octal positional system. Octal represents base 8. 
Which can be represented using 1 bit with values from 0-7 inclusive - a total of 8, that's why it's called octal.

Unrelated: In binary, three 1's represent 1+2+4 = 7.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this.

```
rwx
111  where 111 is a binary value

1 1 1      (binary)
4+2+1 -> 7 (decimal by position)

So 751 would be rwx r_x __x
                111 101 001 (binary)
                421 401 001 (decimal by position)
                 7   5   1  (decimal equivalent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered this confusion. The dashes are the confusing part. One would assume that the dashes are used to separate the permission groups (7-5-1), but the dashes are not used that way in this case; there is no spacing between the permission groups and the dashes are used in the 'middle' of the permission group, so to speak, as a placeholder for nonexistence.

*In short, the dashes are not used to separate the permission groups.*

Answer (score 0):

As Octavian says above the dashes are not used to separate user/group/all but they are used for 0 permissions. In your case if you wish to look at the user/group/all separation it would look like this:

```
755 would be drwxr-xr-x where you can separate like this: drwx|r-x|r-x
751 would be drwxr-x--x where you can separate like this: drwx|r-x|--x
```